# Is this an acceptable use of the comma operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've seen other posts on Stack Overflow which highly discourage overloading of the comma operator.  I was sent a Github pull request with a comma operator overload which looked something like the following:

```
class Mylogger {
    public:
            template <typename T>
            Mylogger & operator,(const T & val) {
                    std::cout << val;
                    return * this;
            }
 };

 #define  Log(level,args...)  \
    do { Mylogger logv; logv,level, ":", ##args; } while (0)
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
 Log(2, "INFO: setting variable \", 1, "\"\n");
```

Can someone explain why this is a good or bad usage case?

Comment: Burn it with fire. This is going to cause all kinds of headaches.

Comment: This effectively translates `,` into `<<`, so just skip that step and do `<<` directly, which everyone already understands.

Comment: The level parameter is being passed into cout, and the string is escaped weirdly so I don't even think it would compile (mismatched quotes).  I think it's a bad sign when the design obscures what should be very obvious behavioral and syntax errors.

Comment: Yea, I didn't want to copy the full the implementation so I hacked that example together. I did say something 'like' the follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's subjective, but I would say it isn't a good usage case because it conveys the wrong semantics. There is already an operator used for output, `<<` would be a better choice.

The code is taking advantage of variadic macros together with overloaded comma operator, which is clever and may be fine for that particular situation. However, if one where to create a `Mylogger` object then the overloaded operator would be confusing and cause all sort of troubles.

So, at the very least, if `Mylogger` was an implementation detail then it *may* be a valid use case. Now in *C++11* with *variadic function templates* there is no need to resort to this kind of twisted code.

Comment: This doesn't look like it is trying to solve the kind of problem that requires a "clever" solution.

Comment: @John: Without _variadic function templates_ you cannot get the same behavior for the same syntax. That said, I think the syntax would better be a chain of `<<` operations. But whoever wrote that code differs, and found a clever solution to what he considers is a problem... **too** clever if you ask me

Answer (score 6):

It would make much more sense to use <<, the comma doesn't usually mean a stream operation and would result in confusing code

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading should *only* be done when the usage is extremely transparent to the caller/user of your class.  When in doubt, just create a method that does what you want, and name it according to good naming conventions.  There is generally no standardized usage for the comma, so adding a comma operator will have the user of your class scratching his/her head.

Recently, I have become a fan of the Google style guide, which isn't a huge fan of ANY operator overloading.  They have some really good reasons you can learn about here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Operator_Overloading